# replace prompt with UI dialog

Tags: user-interface, prompt

How can I replace the prompt in this code with a simple UI dialog to achieve the same thing. IE is warning about security when using prompt.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="textbox1">
<input type="button" id="btn" name="buttonExecute" value="Enter number">
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    var n = prompt('Please enter number');
    if ( n!=null && n!="" ) {

    var fixed=n.substr(1,9);

     $('#txt1').val(fixed);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use jQuery UI.

See a simple demo here. http://jsfiddle.net/5yhmb/23/

Comment: very good but I tried to put this code in and it won't work. var fixed=text2.substr(1,9);
                $('#txt1').val(fixed);

Comment: @Ntguy, you need use text2.val().substr(1,9); http://jsfiddle.net/maheshep/5yhmb/21/ because $('#txt1') return an input object not string.

Comment: @Ntguy, I used query jQuery and jQueryUI. you will have to download it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the jQuery UI Dialog widget: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/