# Alternative to prompt() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

Here's the scenario. I have some JavaScript code that would be generated on the fly. So, instead of using the `prompt()` which opens up an inputbox for reading userinput, I made a custom element. Because I can style my custom inputbox rather than using the normal one.

So, the function to show the custom inputbox is something like, `show_input()`

And this code generated on the fly, is executed at the end using `eval()`. So in code, after calling that `show_input()` function, the program is supposed to wait until the user enters the value and presses the button(the button in my custom made input form). And there would be more than one calls to this function in the generated code.

I am not sure how to find a solution to this. That is, to make it behave just like the `prompt()` halting the entire execution of the code.

What I have tried is, using a boolean flag which would be set when user enter the value and presses the button, in our custom input box. So, when my `show_input()` is called, it would show the custom input box and then enters into an infinite loop which would halt only when this boolean flag in set. But this freezes the webpage making it not responding. So, that's not a great solution.

Is there any way to mimic the functionality of how the `prompt()` function works. I mean, pause the entire page until the user presses the button?

`setTimeout()` function wouldn't be a good choice in my case. Because the reason is, my code generated would look something like this:

```
statement1;
statement2;

show_input(); //call the function to show my custom inputbox

statement3;

show_input();

statement4;
statement5;
// etc...
```

So, after `statement2`, the function call is for displaying the custom input box asking the user to enter the value and press a button. Only after pressing this button, it should goto `statement3`. Till that time, it should wait for the user to press the button in my custom input box.

I am using jQuery and the button had a click event added to it.

The above code generated at runtime, is executed using `eval()`

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: What exactly is this `input()` you're talking about? It's not native JavaScript.

Comment: use events. that means you will have to make your code less secuential. for example, after calling `show_input()` you should not have more code "waiting". Your code should finish, and once the user fires an event (OK button) you will execute another function.

Comment: Your best bet would be to use [showModalDialog()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.showModalDialog), otherways this is not possible with JavaScript.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Extremely sorry for that. Made a typo. It's the built in `prompt()` function of which I am trying to create the alternative to. VB6, VB.Net, PHP, Javascript and everything just made my head banging. :P

Comment: @TheBronx: Thanks. But I'm having doubt on how to make it work. I mean, the generated code at runtime won't be same. And this code would be executed when user presses a button.

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran oh lol.. in that case, what about the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235409/replace-prompt-with-ui-dialog)?

Comment: @Teemu: That's better than the normal `prompt()`. We can modify the looks too. But the only problem with that is, the new modal dialog opened is not showing modally to the current page. If it was showing like a `prompt()` box, would have been better ! I mean, it should be shown modally to the parent calling page (ie. parent tab/window of the browser).

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not _real_ modals, please check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8teZj/). You can also read some of [these posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]sleep) at SO.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: No that won't help. Try echoing the value prior and after calling that form. Both the values would be printed at first! It's not like actually pausing the script. It's just doing a callback on button press!

Comment: So I fear what you ask for is simply not possible, sorry! :(

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran There has been some difficulties in Chrome (it's said that an opened dialog is not really modal in Chrome). Other browsers are doing fine with `showModalDialog()`, i.e. scripts really wait for an answer from a modal dialog. I've emulated modal windows in HTAs with ActiveX, but that's probably not a solution in your case.

Comment: @Teemu: Yeah you're right. Doesn't work in Chrome. But works fine with Firefox!

Comment: @ShadowWizard: There seems to be some tweaks or something available. Lets try digging more. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The execution model of javascript does not allow what you are trying to achieve, since there is no way to "block" execution of a script waiting for input from the DOM. Like you noted with your loop attempt, the page is frozen until the script end running, and only then normal event handling is resumed.

So instead create a callback function containing the statements you want executed after the user input, and have your input system call it. example:

```
// statement 1 and 2 here

var callback = function(value) {
    // statement 3 here
}

show_input(callback);
```

Then inside show_input bind the user confirmation to a function that retrieves the value and then calls the callback function given to it using said value. example (using jquery syntax for brevity, but that's not strictly necessary to use it):

```
function show_input(callback) {
   // create the input form
   $(confirm_button).click(function() {
      callback($(input).value());
   });
```

This can of course be nested to any level as needed. When nesting, care must be taken if reusing existing widgets (as opposed to creating new ones) that the previous callback events are unbound before binding the new ones - if needed, you could also keep a reference to the event handler in order to remove it explicitly, but for most cases unbinding all events should suffice.

See an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YTcy8/

Comment: Thanks. And sorry for the delay in responding. Was reading one by one. I was trying to find whether there is a better solution to this. I think I would probably end up with something like this.

Comment: Tested out and this seems to be the best solution. Thanks :)

Comment: hmm.. I like this method and was testing it. But seems to be not working when nested. Can you please check that?

Comment: There are a few things to take care when nesting, depending on how you use it. I added a note and an example to my answer.

Comment: Brilliant! Ahh! Fiddling with more than an hour. And it was just because of the that event! When I tried for two functions, the first function was repeated again before the second one at output. And the second didn't echoed the value at all! And when I tried with three functions, it went infinite. That's what I was trying figure out for past 2 hours. :P

Answer (score 1):

I found your scenario difficult to follow but assume the difficulty you're facing is with binding user interaction to generated code. To try and get a bit clearer on the issues you're facing, would the following work? If not, why not?

```
$('#thebutton').on('click', statement3);
```

[Here's a fiddle with an abstraction of the whole thing](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/HkARv/) — use the fork button to create your own modifications if you want to extend or correct it.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't help. Because what I am trying to do is creating the javascript code at runtime (a few lines of code only) and then executing it via the `eval()`. So, the problem is with using the alternative `input()`. I want the code to be paused, until the user presses the button. Please note that I have the events attached to the buttons and other things. And have a global boolean flag which would be set when the button is pressed by the user(the one on my custom input box).

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this 'alternative `input()`' is? I don't really understand at the moment. As far as executing generated code, [I updated my example to use a textarea to contain any code you want as a proof of concept for executing code that isn't known at runtime](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/HkARv/1/) — it will execute as part of `statement3` when the user hits the button. I still think a clarified use case explaining what's generated, what isn't, what `input()` means, and what you mean by 'pause', would be a good idea…

Comment: Sorry for typo. Used the wrong name of function. It's `prompt()`, the inputbox.

Comment: It strikes me there are several questions here. One that's just become clear to me is that, when the prompt appears, you want to block all interaction until the user has submitted their input, in other words, made the UX synchronous. Sadly, there's no way to do that per se, but you can use this library to block user interaction. You would then need to make sure any other scripts in your code were aware of the flag and returned false if it was on…

Comment: When the cusomt prompt appears, I want to pause the currently executing(sequentially) piece of javascript code, until the user enters the value and presses the button.

Answer (score 1):

You need to detect the click event on the button of your input box. You can use `onclick` to trigger a function that detects if the user filled the input, if the input is filled then you continue to do what you want. You can also use a [overlay box](http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/index.html) to put the input and button

Comment: Thanks. I know that part and I have already implemented it. It's not that what I am having issue with. Trying to halt the execution of the program. And then resume it after input.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar situation where we had to stop the script execution for user input, we couldn't find any solution after searching for almost 2 3 months. After that we gave up the idea since it isn't possible to do that.

However the approach we took was as follows

```
statement 1
statement 2
showInput(function() { 
    statement3;
    showInput( function() {
               statement4;
               statement5;
             })   
       })
```

I do not have any solution for your problem except this one. If you find a solution other than this please provide the same. I have found many people who are blocked at the same situation